# Mule Dataweave throws an exception sometimes

Tags: mule, dataweave

I am using Dataweave to transform messages. Some times I am getting below exception:

```
Exception stack is:
1. com.mulesoft.weave.reader.json.JsonArray$$anon$1 cannot be cast to com.mulesoft.weave.model.structure.ObjectSeq (java.lang.ClassCastException)
  com.mulesoft.weave.engine.ast.selectors.KeyValueSelectorNode:141 (null)
```

Some times it is not throwing that exception. Can any one solve the issue?

Comment: Please provide more information, what are you transforming?, the dw script,  your expected input/output.

Answer (score 0):

I can tell you exactly what it is.  You have a construct like:
(payload.object.*array map {
})

but object does not exist in the payload therefore there's no array to map.